# How can read automaticaly sms on ionic capacitor app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Good evening I am a beginner in `ionic` `angular` and I need help to read sms with `ionic 6` angular using `capacitor` for native features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms-retriever"

Comment: I agree with @RaviAshara to use sms-retriver plugin from ionic. Anyway it´s not easy to describe each step. I am adding the link https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-automatically-read-sms-in-ionic-5-apps/175/ . In the link there is everything described step by step.